# Google OneTap SignIn Pass or Error codes: 10 / 16

Tags: android, google-one-tap

I'm trying to set up a Google OneTap SignIn button to my developed App (I'm not using Firebase to sign in) guiding by this source:
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started

I've created both OAuth & Web credentials on Cloud Console. To generate OAuth Id I took SHA1 which was provided by Android Studio in signing-in report (I took develop SHA-1, but they are all the same anyway).

I've put to `R.string.default_web_client_id` the Client Id from WebAuth (Not an Android Id from OAuth).

As I use Firebase RTDB for storing some data, I set this SHA-1 there as well. The project name in Manifest, Cloud Console and Firebase Console are the same. From Firebase I downloaded "google-services.json" and put it in app root. On Firebase I also set valid service email.

This is how I implemented OneTap on login activity:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  ...
  private lateinit var oneTapClient: SignInClient
  private lateinit var signUpRequest: BeginSignInRequest
  ...

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
        oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this)
        signUpRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setPasswordRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
                .setSupported(false)
                .build())
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                .setSupported(true)
                // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                .build())
            // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
            .build()
    }

  // THIS CALLED FROM FRAGMENT WHEN GOOGLE BUTTON IS CLICKED
  fun onGoogleClick() {
        when (GoogleApiAvailability().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(applicationContext)) {
            0 -> {
                beginGoogleSignIn()
            }
            1 -> {
                toaster.show("Google services required")
            }
            2 -> {
                toaster.show("Google services update required")
            }
        }
    }

  private fun beginGoogleSignIn() {
        val tag = "$atag-beginGoogleSignIn"
        oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signUpRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this) { result ->
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                        result.pendingIntent.intentSender, library.GOOGLE_SIGNIN_REQUEST_CODE,
                        null, 0, 0, 0)
                } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    logg.d(atag, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: ${e.localizedMessage}")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
                // No Google Accounts found. Just continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                toaster.show("Please sign in to your google account on your phone")
                logg.d(tag, e.localizedMessage)
            }
    }

  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        val tag = "$atag-onActivityResult"
        
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == library.GOOGLE_SIGNIN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            try {
                val credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data)
                token = credential.googleIdToken
                when {
                    token != null -> {
                        // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                        // with your backend.
                        login = credential.id
                        name = credential.displayName
                        avatarUrl = credential.profilePictureUri.toString()
                        tryToLogin()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        // Shouldn't happen.
                        logg.d(atag, "No ID token!")
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                when (e.statusCode) {
                    CommonStatusCodes.CANCELED -> {
                        toaster.show("Please sign in to your google account on your phone")
                        logg.d(tag, "One-tap dialog was closed.")
                        // Don't re-prompt the user.
                    }
                    CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR -> {
                        logg.d(tag, "One-tap encountered a network error.")
                        // Try again or just ignore.
                    }
                    else -> {
                        logg.d(tag, "Couldn't get credential from result." +
                            " (${e.localizedMessage})")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that on some of AVD it works well, on other AVD id gives an Error:

```
16: Cannot find a matching credential.
```

However on this AVD Google Services is up to date, and user is logged in to Google Play

On real device I got this error:

```
10: Caller not whitelisted to call this API.
```

Google services is also up to date here and user is logged in to Play Store.

Everywhere I used my real gmail address.

What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**

Spending a lot of time trying to solve this I have just figured out that OneTap is working on some devices, and is not working on other. Also tried to re-create credentials several times.

Not having very much time to solve this I just use both OneTap way and alternate way to sign in with Google credentials.

```
// In activity

lateinit var oneTapClient: SignInClient
lateinit var signUpRequest: BeginSignInRequest
private lateinit var gso: GoogleSignInOptions
lateinit var mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

private fun initApp() {
    oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this)
        signUpRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setPasswordRequestOptions(
                BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(false)
                    .build()
            )
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                    .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                    .build()
            )
            // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
            .build()
        gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .build()
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
}



// Somewhere else in fragment, 'parent' is reference to activity

// Call this when button clicked
private fun beginGoogleSignIn() {
        parent.oneTapClient.beginSignIn(parent.signUpRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(parent) { result ->
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                        result.pendingIntent.intentSender, state.library.GOOGLE_SIGNIN_REQUEST_CODE,
                        null, 0, 0, 0, null)
                } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    stopSignIn("Couldn't start One Tap UI: ${e.localizedMessage}")
                }
            }
            .addOnCanceledListener(parent) {
                stopSignIn("Cancelled")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(parent) { e ->
                // Use alternate sign in
                val signInIntent = parent.mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, state.library.GOOGLE_ALT_SIGNIN_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == state.library.GOOGLE_SIGNIN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            try {
                handleOneTapSignIn(data)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                val message: String
                when (e.statusCode) {
                    CommonStatusCodes.CANCELED -> {
                        message = "Please sign in to your google account on your phone"
                        // Don't re-prompt the user.
                    }
                    CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR -> {
                        // Try again or just ignore.
                        message = "One-tap encountered a network error."
                    }
                    else -> {
                        message = "Couldn't get credential from result." +
                            " (${e.localizedMessage})"
                    }
                }
                stopSignIn(message)
            }
        } else if (requestCode == state.library.GOOGLE_ALT_SIGNIN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            try {
                handleAlternateSignIn(data)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                if (e.statusCode == 12501) {
                    // Dismissed
                    stopSignIn()
                } else {
                    stopSignIn("${e.statusCode}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
    private fun handleOneTapSignIn(data: Intent?) {
        val credential = parent.oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data)
        val token = credential.googleIdToken
        when {
            token != null -> {
                // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                // with your backend.
                login = credential.id
                avatarUrl = credential.profilePictureUri?.toString() ?: ""
                tryToLogin()
            }
            else -> {
                // Shouldn't happen.
                stopSignIn("No ID token!")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleAlternateSignIn(data: Intent?) {
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        try {
            val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            login = account.email!!
            token = account.idToken ?: ""
            avatarUrl = account.photoUrl?.toString() ?: ""
            tryToLogin()
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            val message = when (e.statusCode) {
                CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR -> {
                    "Could not reach network"
                }
                else -> {
                    "SignIn failed with exception $e"
                }
            }
            stopSignIn(message)
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

It seems `16: Cannot find a matching credential` on Android Emulators is related not to user credentials attempting to sign in, but an app credential in Google Cloud Console.
The issue is not reproduced in my case when I filled consent page at Google Cloud Console as described at [Get started with One Tap sign-in and sign-up](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started)
(I have left empty fields for links to EULA, etc.). Then I have changed package name (for another reasons), then double check that this package name was the same in both credentials configs on Google Cloud Console and in google-services.json. Also I checked that google-services.json is located under `[project_root]/app` directory.

I will check this on real device in a few days.

Comment: Hi，I have the same problem, did you find out the reason?

Comment: I am also getting this error : Caller not whitelisted to call this API

Comment: @Arnold added related info under the 'update' part in the topic question

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your example. In my case the one-tap sign in client just stopped working on ONE device one day even after working fine for months. So I ended up doing the fallback implementation like you and it works just fine.

Comment: Using this implementation for some time I would suggest that on devices with earlier versions of android (6.0 or close to it) OneTap SignIn is not working and throws an error with code 16 about not finding matched credentials. On the more modern devices OneTap sign in works well. However I've got an error with code 10 about device is not whitelisted to call API and this occurs as far as I can remeber when I make an app build on another laptop or another OS, so AndroidStudio on them has different SHA-1 key from my primary one, and this was solved when I added this SHA-1 key to Cloud console.